# Подгрузка игровой карты в отдельном потоке

Tags: многопоточность, разработка-игр, архитектура

**С чем я имею дело:**
Имеется 2D игра с видом сверху. Карта в игре - тайловая, процедурно генерируемая, размер - бесконечный.  Коротко об архитектуре игры: вся игра поделена на четыре модуля - физика, графика, логика, система событий. Эти модули выполняются в одном потоке (далее я буду называть его главным). Каждый объект в игре содержит по одному компоненту физики, графики и логики. Эти компоненты хранятся и обрабатываются соответствующими системами.

**Что нужно сделать и какая у меня возникла проблема:**
Поскольку карта бесконечная - прогружается небольшой участок карты фиксированного размера. При приближении игрока к краям карты - необходимо сгенерировать новые участки карты, а старые удалить вместе со всеми объектами на них. Генерация может занимать до нескольких секунд, поэтому я решил вынести её в отдельный модуль который будет выполняться в собственном потоке. Но у меня возникли трудности с тем, как с точки зрения архитектуры организовать 
взаимодействие модуля генерации с остальными модулями в игре.

**Как я пытаюсь решить задачу:**
когда персонаж подходит к границе - просыпается поток в котором обрабатывается модуль генерации. Далее модуль генерации начинает генерировать мир, добавляя объекты в специальные буферы предоставляемые модулем физики, графики и логики. Когда генерация завершена, модуль генерации посылает событие в систему событий и засыпает. Система событий, в момент обновления в главном потоке, оповещает логику, физику и графику что генерация завершена. Те в свою очередь меняют местами текущие хранилища на буфера. Я выбрал этот подход, т.к. мы заполняем буфер НЕ ОБРАЩАЯСЬ К ОБЪЕКТАМ в хранилище модуля, что облегчает синхронизацию между потоками; нам не надо тратить время на добавление объектов из буфера в хранилище, а также на поиск и удаление объектов оказавшихся за пределами карты. 
Исходя из описанного к буферу предъявляются следующие требования:

1. Буфер представляет собой ту же структуру данных, что и хранилище соответствующего модуля.
2. В момент, когда модули получив событие об окончании генерации, меняют местами хранилище и буфер - в буфере должна содержаться только актуальная информация. Нужно учитывать, что в хранилищах модулей из главного потока будут удаляться и добавляться объекты во время работы модуля генерации.
3. При приближении игрока к краям прогруженного участка карты - он смещается. Нужно определить, какие объекты остались в пределах карты. Они должны попасть в буфер.

**Собственно вопросы, которые у меня возникли:**

1. Для хранения динамических физических компонентов используется дерево квадрантов. Как определить, какие компоненты останутся в пределах прогруженного участка карты после завершения текущей генерации, если в главном потоке 
   обрабатывающем физический модуль компоненты могут постоянно добавляться и удаляться?
2. Для хранения различных компонентов логики используются обычные списки. Вопрос тот же, что и выше.
3. Статические физические компоненты хранятся в одномерном массиве чанков. Они располагаются не дискретно относительно чанков и тайлов. Могут быть как очень маленькими, так и очень большими. Вопрос следующий: допустим мы подгружаем новый участок карты и генерируем на нем дом. Дом должен располагаться на границе с ранее загруженным чанком, который сейчас обрабатывается модулем физики в другом потоке. Мы можем добавить дом при условии, что на занимаемом им месте нет ни одного статического  или динамического физического компонента. На момент проверки генерации дома это условие соблюдалось и дом был добавлен в буфер. Но модуль физики ничего не знает о модуле генерации и не может заглянуть в буфер, пока не закончится генерация, также будем помнить что динамические и статические физические компоненты хранятся отдельно. Далее, допустим игрок встал на то место, где в буфере находится дом (в главном хранилище это место пустое). И тут генерация закончилась и модуль физики поменял местами буфер и хранилище. Получается - игрок оказался внутри дома не заходя в него. Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Вопрос очень обширный. Коротко - есть методы синхронизации, есть volatile метка/признак.  Разпаралелить - всё можно. Главное - синхронизировать после - иначе получится каша. Прийдется замедлять синхронизацией процесс так, что б не возникало ситуации "вдруг дома не было, а потом оказалось что он там есть"

Comment: Ещё короче - разпаралелили -> синхронизировали. Иначе не получится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем случае, это решается подгрузкой частей уровня на таком расстоянии от игрока, чтобы загрузка прошла быстрее, чем игрок сможет туда попасть. Т.е. начинайте грузить так, чтобы когда игрок (и действия с физикой и логикой вокруг него) подошли к границам, всё было уже загружено.

Также, вы можете добавить "зоны безопасности" вдоль границ частей уровня, чтобы исключить попадание в них сущностей, которые могли бы оказаться заблокированными. То есть А - не ставьте маршруты двигающихся NPC и дома на границах частей уровня, чтобы они не наложились друг на друга при подгрузке. И Б - если часть уровня все еще грузится, не давайте ничему попасть в окрестности границы.

*На Хабре была статья про то как это сделано в Мире Танков, можете поискать.*

Comment: Спасибо, Kromster. А что вы бы могли посоветовать по 1 и 2 вопросам?

Comment: Совет уже содержится в ответе - грузите все тогда когда в области подгрузки ничего динамического не происходит.